# How to include firmware to Ubuntu Server Install?

Tags: 18.04, server, system-installation, firmware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a HP ProLiant DL360 G7. During the initial boot I receive the error "can't load firmware file bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1b.fw" ... I was able to locate the firmware files and I've tried placing them in the root directory and into /firmware directory that I made on the USB drive that has the install for Ubuntu as per the instructions found at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/arm64/ch06s04.html. For some reason the install can't find the files. I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing on how to get the install to recognize the firmware files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file needs to be in: `/lib/firmware/bnx2/`. Is that where you put it?

Comment: I'm trying to get the installation to recognize the firmware during installation. I will try to make a directory /lib/firmware/bnx2/ on the USB and see if it sees the files that way. Currently I have the .fw files on the root and a directory I made called firmware but the install isn't seeing them.

Comment: Placing the files into /lib/firmware/bnx2/, /firmware/, /firmware/bnx2/ and / still will not  cause the installer to detect the files.

Comment: After many hours of reading and trying to get this to work I finally gave in and installed it without network adapters. After successful installation I logged into the machine and mounted the usb drive containing the firmware. I then copied the .fw file to /lib/firmware/bnx2/ and then ip link to see the name of the devices (since it changed from eth0 to enp3s0f0) and then ran dhclient enp3s0f0 to get ip address from the DHCP and now it works.

Comment: Glad it's working by whatever means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, on a Gigabyte 1U server, but I found a good solution.

My solution:

```
    [ALT] + [F2]
    [Enter]
    sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

This installs lots of firmware files in /lib/firmware. It also triggers reloading the NIC driver. (Could see this using `dmesg` in the second terminal)

Return to the installer:

```
     [ALT] + [F1]
```

Select NIC -> IPv4 -> DHCP and it grabbed a v4 DHCP address on the bench network.

Continue the install, reboot, and all is well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I recently had to reinstall Ubuntu on to my server and I needed to do the whole process again and can confirm your steps worked. Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!